# How do I test the FOR loop data for this code?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, loop, for

I have written a test class for a class and its coverage is above 75% but I want to increase it and found that a particular for loop is not being covered(written Between ** below). Please help me with this. I don't have the idea how to test for the for a loop.

```
myContactList= Database.query(queryString);
            for(Contact c : myContactList){
                **RecData recordsData = new RecData ();
                RecData.value= String.valueOf(c.get('id'));
                RecData.label = String.valueOf(c.get(filterField));
                RecData.cont = c;
                recDataList.add(recordsData);**
            } 
        } catch (Exception err) {}
        return recDataList;
    }
```

Here the the RecData is the inner wrapper class with three properties which are covered in test class.

Answer (score 0):

To make this code more testable, you need to extract the loop body to a separate code unit. In your case there are 2 options:

1. RecData constructor
2. Just a separate method

Then just write tests for that extracted unit. That would do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

The point of tests is to confirm that the code does what the requirements specified so start with that mindset when writing tests. Code coverage is just a crude indicator.

The data already in your org is (except for some special cases) not visible to your test. So your test will need to insert data that causes your `queryString` query to return rows so that the loop executes.

Also 99% of the time this `} catch (Exception err) {}` is a bad idea; normally better to let the exception bubble up so you know something has gone wrong.